# How to solve Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error in React js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, api

I am building a react js application with dummy backend using `json-server`.I am implementing a dropdown list but I am getting `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error` on fetching from api.The api is working fine in browser but while fetching in react it is giving me this error.

My component:

```
import React from 'react';

var values;

class ApiDropDown extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            options: []
        }  
    }

   componentDidMount(){
       this.fetchOptions()
    }

    fetchOptions(){
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/groups')
            .then((res) => {
                
                return res.json();
            }).then((json) => {
                values = json;
                this.setState({options: values.groups})
                console.log(values);
            });
    }
    render(){
    
        return <div>
            <select>
                { this.state.options.map((option, key) => <option key={key} >{option}</option>) }
            </select>
            </div>;
    



}
}

export default ApiDropDown;
```

My db.json for dummy backend:

```
{  
  "groups":[  
     {  
        "key":"version",
        "apis":"system_info"
     },
     {  
        "key":"admin",
        "name":"patients"
     },
     {  
        "id":"admin2",
        "name":"doctors"
     }
     
  ]
}
```

Here's how I am rendering my ApiDropDown component:

```
 return (
    <form className="add-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <div>
      <ApiDropDown/> //ApiDropDown Component
      </div>
      <div >
        <input className="clientparams"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add Client"
          value={client_name}
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      </form>
```

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: In your console log can you see your data perfectly?

Comment: yes I am getting the data in console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that should be correct.

1. `{ this.state.options.map((option, key) => <option key={key} >{option}</option>) }` In this you are trying to bind the object as react child, so instead of this it should be `{{ this.state.options.map((option, key) => <option key={key} >{option["apis"]}</option>) }`
2. You no need to declare a variable to store the fetch values you can directly set it to state like this. `this.setState({options: json.groups})`

Here is the working example of your code(fetch call is different): https://codesandbox.io/embed/nifty-lamport-mzmro?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

You're not using fetch right:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/groups').then((res) => {
  res.json().then((json) => {
    values = json;
    this.setState({options: values.groups})
    console.log(values);
  })
})
```